# OkHttpClient self signed certificate

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, retrofit, okhttp

Need to connect android app(retrofit REST API) with a server that has self signed certificate, so I have to trust this certificate.

I have to use: file_certificate.crt, file_chain.chain and file_key.key

In linux I run this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.host.com:443 -state -tls1_2 -key file_key.key -cert file_certificate.crt -CAfile file_chain.chain
```

and connection is done successfully `... Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

So how to create an OkHttpClient to using these 3 files, because all I find is using a single CA file like so:

```
 public static OkHttpClient createClient(Context context) {

    OkHttpClient client = null;

    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    InputStream cert = null;
    Certificate ca = null;
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file_certificate); // Place your 'my_cert.crt' file in `res/raw`

        ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
        cert.close();

        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
                .build();

    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return client;
}
```

Comment: The arguments `-cert` and `-key` for `openssl s_client` have nothing to do with validating the server certificate but they are used for authentication using a client certificate (mutual authentication). Thus you should not ask how to use the three files to validate the server but how to use a given certificate and key for client authentication. [This search](https://www.google.com/search?q=okhttp+client+certificate) might lead you to the answer and examples.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you for pointing me to the right way. As I see there is no easy way to do it within okhttp client, so I wonder if that's even possible?

Comment: I have no experience with okhttp myself but one of the first hits in the search [looks like a working example](https://gist.github.com/milhomem/cd322bf3d0599ceb76fe). It needs to have the certificate + key as pkcs12 though but this [can be created from certificate and key](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+cert+key+pkcs12)

Comment: Did you solve your problem?